# Error during invocation setup

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to implement facebook login in my app and when i "cmd" + click on FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate to copy/paste the required functions i get this warning:

```
Couldn't Generate Swift Representation
               Error (from SourceKit):
               "Error during invocation setup"
```

I'm implementing the two functions to silence the warning that the "ViewController does not conform to protocol ..." and it's not complaining anymore, but am afraid it can bring some problems in the future.
I've used Cocoapods to install the API and i've installed Firebase too.

I don't have problems on "cmd" + click on other protocols, classes, etc.

Anyone knows what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me because my project name and the directory holding the framework had a space in it's name. Changing that has fixed my documentation issues.